# What is "the work of God" in Romans 14:20?

Tags: romans

**Romans 14:20**

> "Do not, for the sake of food, destroy **the work of God.** Everything is indeed clean, but it is wrong for anyone to make another stumble by what he eats." ESV. My emphasis.

What is "the work of God" that can be destroyed?

**Matthew 16:18**

> "...I will build my church, and the gates of hell shall not prevail against it." ESV.

Since "our Lord Jesus Christ" [1 Cor 1:2] has said that He will build His church and "the gates of hell will not prevail against it", what is "**the work of God**" that does not prevail in that it can be destroyed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the two cases is that the threat which Paul fears in Romans is less complete than the threat which is denied in Matthew.

"Prevail against" is KATISCHUO, defined by Thayer's lexicon as being "strong to another's detriment, to be superior in strength, to overpower". Jesus denies that the gates of hell can overcome the community of the church as a whole. Whereas "God's work" in Romans ch14 is more localised, referring to his work among individuals.

To explain the comment in Romans, we need to go back to the beginning of the chapter. This is all about protecting those who are "weak in faith"  and avoiding unnecessary "disputes over opinions" (v1). We ought to avoid passing judgement unnecessariy (v4, v10, v13), but also (from v14) we should avoid doing things which might provoke others into making hasty judgements. So the destruction which is being threatened here is the more partial kind, that God's work in individuals may be undermined.

Comment: I put +1 as helpful. But the community/individual contrast I think is not clear as community is made of individuals. If the faith of individuals be destroyed that is something happening in the community. Could katalye/destroy be "unharnessed", a loosening but not total destruction, just a bit of a shake up with recovery possible?

Comment: Perhaps the expression "destroy" is over-strong, as is natural when somebody is giving a warning he wants to be taken seriously. But I think the church would have to disappear altogether to justify the claim that the powers of hell had "prevailed".

Comment: I acknowledge and agree with your "over-strong" comment.

Comment: On consideration I do not think your "over-strong" is necessarily an empty threat.[ Does God make empty threats?]  i.e. It might be that the "work of God" here refers to those who go a little way towards the kingdom, for awhile they are going towards heaven, but not being of the elect are not given the grace to persevere.